# Symbol not found: _TA-ACOS - Python Wrapper for TA-Lib not Importing

Tags: python, apple-m1, ta-lib

I have been trying to use TA-Lib. However when I try to import it, I get the following error:

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/talib/_ta_lib.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _TA_ACOS

TA-Lib is showing that it is installed.

I am running a Mac with an M1 chip.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And there is a talib library?  The _ta_lib.cpython-39-darwin.so is just a wrapper for it. The real library shall be somewhere else. Have you build it? How you got _ta_lib.cpython-39-darwin.so? Via `pip install`?

Comment: MacBook-Air talib % ls
__init__.py   test_abstract.py
__pycache__   test_data.py
_ta_lib.cpython-38-darwin.so test_func.py
abstract.py   test_pandas.py
deprecated.py   test_stream.py"

Comment: these're wrapper files